# Browser Differences with Media Query Trigger Points

Tags: css, cross-browser, media-queries

I've noticed that the media query breakpoints get triggered differently in Chrome vs all other browswers (IE9, Chrome, Opera).

Refer to the following screenshots to help explain (please ignore the placeholder pictures).  First, where the breakpoint is in chrome:

[image]

Now, let's take a look below at where the media query triggers for all other browsers.  We will use Firefox as the example, but it is the same for IE9 and Opera.

[image]

The differences:

1. In chrome, the trigger point for the media query is at 1190px.  In all other browsers, the trigger point is at 1173px.  The difference is 17px.
2. 17px is also the difference between the actual width of the browser
   itself.  What do I mean by that?  I took a screenshot of the point before and after the media query triggers on both Chrome and Firefox.  In photoshop, I kept the width of the jpg image consistent for both browsers.  For some reason, the media query triggers 17px earlier in every browser except Chrome.

The actual media query CSS code:

```
@media (min-width: 1190px) and (max-width: 1254px) {

    .visible-large {
        display: inherit !important;
    }

}


@media (max-width: 1189px) {

    .visible-large {
        display: none !important;
    }

}
```

My question: **Is there any way to get the media query to trigger at the same point in all browsers?**

Answer (score 2):

I think some browsers may count overflow width.

Comment: You are suggesting that something like a negative margin could be causing the difference?

Comment: I mean that chrome doesn't count the scrollbar width for the media queries but the others do.

Comment: Is there any way to force all browsers to measure consistently with regards to media queries?

Comment: $('body').innerWidth(); should give you correct width but this is for jquery i have no idea how to get correct width with media queries.

Comment: I +1'ed for getting me on the right track as I think you are correct in thinking that IE9, Firefox and Opera include the scrollbar width when calculating media queries.  As for the answer, the search goes on!

Comment: you may try "@media (-webkit-animation)" for chrome and calculate the diffrence i dont if its going to work but don't forget safari uses webkit too

Comment: Where would I apply the webkit?

Comment: at the end of css file. it will overwrite the other rules.
@media (min-width: 1190px) and (max-width: 1254px) and  (-webkit-animation) { here you will write for chrome. }

Answer (score 0):

The real difference is the way chrome-based browsers consider window/document width. In chrome based browsers the right scroll bar width is not taken into account (possibly because the mobile browser has to do this - the scroll bars in mobile browsers are "virtual" and placed in front of the document, not outside of the document's width).

As far as I know, the only way to normalize the document-to-window width for media queries across browsers can only be done in javascript because of the way chrome-based browsers handle the scroll bar, which sort of negates the power media queries brought to CSS in the first place.