# How to Force All Browsers to Measure Viewport Width Consistently for Media Queries

Tags: css, cross-browser, media-queries

Apparently Chrome does not include the scrollbar width (~17px) when evaluating media queries.

IE, Firefox and Opera do count the scrollbar width as part of the viewport.

For example, assume a viewport width of 500px and a scrollbar of 17px.

The below code:

```
@media (min-width: 500) {

    //code

}
```

will execute in **Chrome** at a **viewport width of greater than or equal to 500px**.

However, **IE9, Firefox & Opera** will execute that code at a **viewport width of greather than or equal to 483px**.

My Question: **Is there a way to force all browsers to either include or exclude the scrollbar width to/from the viewport width when executing media queries?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser Differences with Media Query Trigger Points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896906/browser-differences-with-media-query-trigger-points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE, Firefox and Opera [follow the W3C spec](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201301/media_query_width_and_vertical_scrollbars/) of including the scrollbar width in the media query, where Webkit browsers do not.

You can't force the browsers to treat it the same at the moment, so the best option is to modify your layout so that it is not so tightly tied to the widths in your media queries (add extra margin). With such a layout, when it triggers a few pixels early or late, it won't make as much of a difference.

Comment: I figured as much but I wanted to make sure there wasn't a way to make all browsers calculate the media queries in the same fashion before making changes to design.  Thanks for your help!